# Ubuntu 20.04 - How can i display the Dock on selected screens individually and Dock have different locations on each monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, dash

[My attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebbiu.jpg)

- I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- I have 3 monitors
- I use Dash to Dock and dconf.

As shown in the attached picture:

- Screen number 1 is the main screen.
- I am setting up Dock at screen number 3, right Dock position.
- I only have 2 options: either show the Dock on all screens or show the Dock on one of the screens

My question:

- Is there a way to show MORE a Dock in screen number 2 with the left position.
- No need to display the Dock in the main screen number 1.

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the answer to your question but I'd be very grateful if you could tell me how to set up 3 monitors on ubuntu 20.04? I have two monitors and one laptop with only one HDMI port.